# Which FIle Form Field For C# Request.Files[n].FileName

Tags: c#, html, file-type

If I have a HTML form with multiple input file fields (where 'N' is a unique number);

```
<input type="file" name="inputFileN">
```

Then in the C# code;

```
string inFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[M].FileName)
```

Is there any way I can ascertain the value of 'M' from the Request data so I can match against a specific HTML input file-type field ?

This is in a situation where the end-user can update the fields on an edit form and it works ok for for all field types apart from the file-type field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of the necessary data is in `HttpContext.Request.Files`; specifically, in `HttpContext.Request.Files.AllKeys`:

```
//HttpContext is a member of `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`,
//accessible in controllers that inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`.
System.Web.HttpFileCollectionBase files = HttpContext.Request.Files;
string[] fieldNames = files.AllKeys;
for (int i = 0; i < fieldNames.Length; ++i)
{
    string field = fieldNames[i]; //The 'name' attribute of the html form
    System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase file = files[i];
    string fileName = files[i].FileName; //The path to the file on the client computer
    int len = files[i].ContentLength; //The length of the file
    string type = files[i].ContentType; //The file's MIME type
    System.IO.Stream stream = files[i].InputStream; //The actual file data
}
```

Comment: Thank you, was scratching my head until you pointed out  "HttpContext.Request.Files.AllKeys"

Answer (score 0):

You could define a file input control on server side which your  would automatically map to.

client side:

```
<input type="file" name="inputFileN" id="inputFileN" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

server side in your page:

```
protected HtmlInputFile inputFileN;
```

Check the documentation on how to get the file content from HtmlInputFile:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputfile.postedfile(v=vs.110).aspx

Not exactly answer to your question but serves the purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the thought but this is WebForms and I'm  using MVC.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select images: <input type="file" name="inputFileN" multiple>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

retrieve file :

```
public void GetFiles()
{
   HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;

   for(int i = 0;i < uploadedFiles.Count;i++) {
          HttpPostedFile userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[i];

   if(userPostedFile.ContentLength > 0) {


   userPostedFile.SaveAs(filepath + "\\" +Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName)); 
  }

}
```

Comment: So instead of getting 1 file I'm getting an array of files and saving them ?

But I still don't have a connection/association between each file and its screen form input field and that's what I'm after ....

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
foreach (string fileID in Request.Files)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileID];
    //do stuff
}
```